# search date between in javascript jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i have a datatable with 2 radios buttons and a search button, i want to put year and date month in 2 and 3 datatable cell, also when i check rb1 and click button datatable search show date clockings between 01 / month / year and 15 / month / year and for the datatable rb2 display punches between 16 / m / y and 31 / moth / year.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="btnf1">1st fortnight</label>
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="btn1" name="btnRadio" checked>

            <label class="form-check-label" for="btnf2">2nd fortnight</label>
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="btn2" name="btnRadio">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
            <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">Rechercher</button>
          </div>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
            <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
                        <th>year</th>
                        <th>month</th>
                        <th>salaries</th>
                        <th>chantier</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="tr_">
                          <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
                          <td>najib</td>
                          <td>harbil</td>
                          <td>01/01/2019</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="tr_">
                          <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
                          <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
                          <td>ali</td>
                          <td>najd</td>
                          <td>20/01/2019</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>year</th>
                        <th>month</th>
                        <th>salaries</th>
                        <th>chantier</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                 </tr>
            </tfoot>
      </table>
```

jQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });
         $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
         });

          let year=$('#year').val();;
          let month=$('#month').val();

           $('.year').val(year);
           $('.month').val(month);
         });
```

Comment: What's with the double semi-colons? That's confusing. `;;` should be `;`.

Comment: Don't forget you don't need to cast a boolean to a boolean. You can just do `$(".checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked',true))` and chain that in.

Comment: `#year and #month` are missing from your example.  What date are we comparing?  The one in the final td of each row?  The values in the hidden input that will always have the Month and Year your searching on?  If the second where am I getting the day value?  If the first what's the purpose of the hidden inputs?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879352/filter-table-list-by-date-range-from-and-to/56929741#56929741